# Some live/hotmail user's are not receiving html mail

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer, spam

I'm sending html emails via phpmailer on my website.
But, for some reason a few live/hotmail users are not receiving my emails.

Regarding my server logs, all the e-mails just send successful to the right email addresses.
When I test with my own (old)hotmail address i'm receiving the emails just fine, but some users complaining they don't.

A test with a new outlook address is also not receiving any email from the website.

The script is sending all the emails with SMTP auth. 
Where do I have to look further?

My test script:

```
include("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication

$mail->Host       = "mail.xxx.nl"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Username   = "info@xxx.nl"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "xxxxx";        // SMTP account password

$mail->From     = "info@xxx.nl";

$mail->AddAddress('xxx@outlook.com');

$mail->AddReplyTo("info@xxx.nl");
$mail->FromName = "De website www.xxx.nl";
$mail->Subject  = 'test';  
$mail->Body     = 'hallo';
$mail->AltBody     = strip_tags('test hallo');


if(!$mail->Send()) 
{ $succes = false; echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;} else { echo 'success';}
```

Comment: Get the recipents to check their spam folders, that's the most likely problem. Beyond that, hotmail does have a history of blackholing email. You might try adding DKIM signing (supported in PHPMailer) to improve deliverability in general.

Comment: I've added DKIM signing and tested on a new outlook address that I just made. Unfortunately, I still don't receive any email, nor in my spam folder. I also checked if my ip is blacklisted, which is not the case. I also had to add a DNS record for DKIM signing. Do I have to wait before the DNS is updated?

Comment: So what does your mail server's log say about that message delivery?

Comment: It says this: 

2014-10-01 15:17:14 1XZJmJ-0004Pl-Hr => xxxx@live.nl F=<info@xxxx.nl> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=1432 H=mx2.hotmail.com [65.55.37.72] X=UNKNOWN:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 C="250  <a1fca452c04dbffed62c83759f3e191d@xxxx.nl> Queued mail for delivery"
2014-10-01 15:17:14 1XZJmJ-0004Pl-Hr Completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Microsoft is receiving the website e-mails.
I didn't had DKIM, SPF records and reverse DNS configured.

Beside that I contacted Microsoft about my problem. For some reason they don't trust new IP addresses.
Now they added the IP to the list save senders and Microsoft users are receiving my e-mails correctly.

Thank you all