# PHP Sending Mail with Headers to Gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

The `mail()` function in PHP works fine when sending to Gmail if I don't specify any headers.  However, as soon as I try to add in headers, the function still returns `true` but I never get the email.  The Gmail server seems to reject the delivery.

These are the headers I'm using:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: ' . $username . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Blahblah <email@example.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($email, 'Subject', '<html><body>Body of message</body></html>', $headers);
```

I was hoping that someone could point out to me the flaw?  I grabbed most of this code straight from the PHP manual, so one could understand my confusion and frustration.  Thanks!

Comment: "The server rejects the delivery" so your looming at the mail server log -what does it *exactly* say ?

Comment: `mail()`'s first parameter is equivalent to "To:", so I don't know why you're adding it in your header.

Comment: @Dagon The `mail()` function returns true, but the email does not arrive.  This is how I know that the server is rejecting its delivery.

Comment: no, it does not mean that at all. all that mail()'s return says is that the local mail agent accepted the mail

Comment: I use google apps, and never had an issue with them $50 / year...worth my users getting my emails vs spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bigger email services will not deliver mail sent from your own personal server in this manner.
Due to SPAM issues.  All the big mail providers require SPF records, DKIM, and reverse DNS before they will accept your mail.

[Some live/hotmail user's are not receiving html mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118451/some-live-hotmail-users-are-not-receiving-html-mail)

Personally I prefer to be rid of that hassle and use a 3rd party mail server for all of my outgoing mails to my users.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Headers .= "From: $Yourname <$YourEmail>\r\n";
```

or

```
$Headers .= 'From: '.$Yourname.'<'.$Youremail.'>'."\r\n";
```

or

```
$Headers .= 'From: '.$Yourname.' <".$Youremail.">' . "\r\n";
```

Give a try if any of this work?